# How does spark report / collect metrics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, metrics

[This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) defines several sinks, metrics and so on. But they are collected?

1. Let say that I added `JxmSink` into `metric.properties` file and enable all instance metrics (master, applications, worker, executor, driver, shuffleService, applicationMaster).
2. Let say that jmx port is set.

Where to collect metrics: should I connect to all cluster nodes or only to driver node?

Comment: You want to collect metric yourslef ? Or Spark provide UI can see those data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark metrics are not required to pull from individual nodes, if respective sink host configured in metric properties file, then metrics will be pushed to it for every configured seconds. Our setup configured to have GraphiteSink to collect the metrics, required configuration for the same as detailed below (along with others you mentioned)

1. Prepare a metrics configuration properties file with Graphite server end point

```
    *.sink.graphite.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink
    *.sink.graphite.host=<graphite-server-host>
    *.sink.graphite.port=<graphite-server-port>
    *.sink.graphite.period=10
    *.sink.graphite.prefix=dev
```

2. Make sure metrics properties file being passed into --files option in spark-submit job script, so that it will be used by executor nodes for sending metrics

Comment: So every node in cluster push metrics to some host? Or they oush metrics to master first?

Comment: @Cherry Yes, executor metrics comes to graphite server directly. Please check this blog for metrics system architecture - http://yusufameri.github.io/Metric-Monitoring-for-your-Spark-Cluster/